# Minimizing properties of geodesics problem in do Carmo's book 2

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading DoCarmo's book Riemannian Geometry and in the section with minimizing properties of geodesics it this proposition.
[image]

At the final I don't understand why $r(1)=l(\gamma).$ Can some one fill in the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\gamma(1)=c(1)$ we know (by uniqueness) that
\begin{equation}
\gamma(t)=exp_p(tr(1)v(1))
\end{equation}
and therefore, as $||v(1)||=1$ the curve $\gamma$ has lengt $r(1).$

Comment: I don't get the fact that $\gamma(t)=exp_p(tr(1)v(1))$, everything in rest is ok!

Comment: In a normal nbhd $U$ around $p,$ the geodesic from $p$ to $q=exp_p(w)$ (which is entirely contained in $U$) is given by $t\to exp_p(tw).$ In this specific case $q=c(1)=exp(r(1)v(1)),$ i.e. $w=r(1)v(1).$

Comment: Oh, got you! Thanks!